# Image not displaying properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a background image to my website, I have set it so that the image will be in fullscreen, the problem is that I can't scroll down to see the rest of the page. Why?

```
<head>
<title>hemsida</title>
</head>

<body>

<img src="bilder/hemsidan.png" 
style='position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;z-index:-1;'>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this :
After head and before body

```
<style>
body  {
    background-image: url("bilder/hemsidan.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;     
}
</style>
```

Remove your tag img

Comment: Putting that after the head and before the body would make that invalid HTML. `<style>` belongs in the `<head>` in almost all cases.

Comment: The thing is, now it doesn't cover the screen, there are white bars on the side, I want the image to be zoomed in and that you can scroll down to see the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to do this :

```css
/* this will add background to your site and below content*/
body {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/800/800/);
  background-size: cover;
}
/* Then put the CSS related to your page*/
.content {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  margin: 30px;
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum v lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum v lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum v lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum v lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a real background image? Do it like this:

```css
body {
  background: url(bilder/hemsidan.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly should I add this? It doesn't seem to work, all I get is a part of the code displaying on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the image as a background image then you should add it as such on the body tag. You can also user it as cover if you want it to fit the whole screen.

```
body {
  background: url('bilder/hemsidan.png') 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
  // background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image in your case is fixed top left and overlays everything.

You can attach the image to the html body as an background image. The following html content is now in front of the background image.

```
<head>
<title>hemsida</title>
</head>

<body style='background: url("bilder/hemsidan.png") 0 0 no-repeat;'>

</body>
</html>
```